# SummitXLPose has no attribute '_request_class'

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following a tutorial from theConstructSim in which I am trying to create a service which when called will write the current coordinate position of the robot to a file.

However, the rospy.service function call is immediately triggering the following error when I perform a rosrun on the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/my_summit_xl_tools/src/spots_to_file.py", line 79, in <module>
    startPoseService()

  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/my_summit_xl_tools/src/spots_to_file.py", line 75, in startPoseService
    summitpose = SummitXLPose()

  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/my_summit_xl_tools/src/spots_to_file.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.pose_service = rospy.Service('/get_pose_summitxl_service', SummitXLPose , self.pose_service_callback)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 711,in __init__
    error_handler)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 544,in __init__
    super(ServiceImpl, self).__init__(name, service_class)

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/service.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.request_class = service_class._request_class
    
AttributeError: type object 'SummitXLPose' has no attribute '_request_class'
```

Here's the code I am running:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
import rospy
from my_summit_xl_tools.srv import SummitXLPose, SummitXLPoseResponse, SummitXLPoseRequest
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseWithCovarianceStamped
import rospkg

"""
# topic: /amcl_pose
# geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped 

std_msgs/Header header                                                                                                                                       
  uint32 seq                                                                                                                                                 
  time stamp                                                                                                                                                 
  string frame_id                                                                                                                                            
geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance pose                                                                                                                        
  geometry_msgs/Pose pose                                                                                                                                    
    geometry_msgs/Point position                                                                                                                             
      float64 x                                                                                                                                              
      float64 y                                                                                                                                              
      float64 z                                                                                                                                              
    geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation                                                                                                                     
      float64 x                                                                                                                                              
      float64 y                                                                                                                                              
      float64 z                                                                                                                                              
      float64 w                                                                                                                                              
  float64[36] covariance
"""

class SummitXLPose(object):
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.loginfo("---> Starting Service ...")
        print(dir(SummitXLPose))
        self.pose_service = rospy.Service('/get_pose_summitxl_service', SummitXLPose , self.pose_service_callback)
        ...
        
    def start_loop_service(self):
        rospy.spin() # mantain the service open.
        
    def pose_service_callback(self, request):
        rospy.loginfo("... testing ...")
        spot_name = request.label
        
        with open(self.spot_file_path, "a") as myfile:
            spot_pose = self.pose_now.pose.pose
            myfile.write(spot_name+":\n"+str(spot_pose)+"\n\n")

        response = SummitXLPoseResponse()
        response.navigation_successfull = True
        response.message = "Spot <"+spot_name+"> Saved"

        return response
    
    def amcl_pose_callback(self, message):
        self.pose_now = message

def startPoseService():
    rospy.init_node('summitxl_poseservice_server')
    summitpose = SummitXLPose()
    summitpose.start_loop_service()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startPoseService()
```

My SummitXLPose service is defined as follows:

```
# request
string label
---
#response
bool navigation_successfull
string message
```

Degugging the SummitXLPose class shows a lot of data but nothing of the request and response of the service that I expected to see as denoted in [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/322139/service-server-and-client-in-python-following-tutorial-does-not-work/) question:

```
[INFO] [1613683896.890733, 0.000000]: ---> Starting Service ...
[
    '__class__', 
    '__delattr__', 
    '__dict__', 
    '__doc__', 
    '__format__', 
    '__getattribute__', 
    '__hash__', 
    '__init__', 
    '__module__', 
    '__new__', 
    '__reduce__', 
    '__reduce_ex__', 
    '__repr__', 
    '__setattr__', 
    '__sizeof__', 
    '__str__', 
    '__subclasshook__', 
    '__weakref__', 
    'amcl_pose_callback', 
    'pose_service_callback', 
    'start_loop_service'
]
```

It seems to me the absence of a **_request_class** attribute in the debug information is clearly the reason for my issue (as shown in the error above as compared to the question linked above) but I don't know how to resolve this issue.

I'd appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372190/summitxlpose-has-no-attribute-%27_request_class%27/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2021-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This one proved to be as simple as it is embarrassing.
The code in the tutorial was a bit flawed in that the class had the same name as the service class. So as far as ROS was concerned, I was attempting to call the same python class.

Instead of the code above, I now have the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
...
from my_summit_xl_tools.srv import SummitXLPose, SummitXLPoseResponse, SummitXLPoseRequest
...

class SummitXLPoseX(object):
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.loginfo("---> Starting Service ...")
        print(dir(SummitXLPose))
        self.pose_service = rospy.Service('/get_pose_summitxl_service', SummitXLPose , self.pose_service_callback)
        ...
        
def startPoseService():
    ...
    summitpose = SummitXLPoseX()
    ...
```

That simple distintion between the python class name and the class name of the service solved my problem.

---

Originally posted by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) with karma: 247 on 2021-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0